# AjaxToolkit Calendar Extender Programmatic change in value not reflected

Tags: asp.net, webforms, calendarextender

There is a calendar image near to the text box for dropdown calendar. When I change the date value in text box by

`$("#calendarTextBox").val("11/22/2004");`

and then if user clicks on the image, the drop down calendar contains the old date value instead of the one set by the javascript.

Any clues will be helpful.

[Calendar Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx) for trying out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

```
$find('<%CalenderExtenderContol.ClientID%>').set_selectedDate(new Date('11/22/2004'));
```